# null value checking

Tags: c#

```
  public string AgentVersion
  {
    get { return m_version; }
  } // property: Enabled
  private string m_version = null;
```

The below declaration coding i did in Constructor

```
  string keySpoPath = SpoRegistry.SpoAgentRoot;
  RegistryKey regkey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keySpoPath);
  m_version = (string)regkey.GetValue(SpoRegistry.regValue_CurrentVersion);
```

here are my doubts

---

1. Do I need `private string m_version = null;` in property declaration in this context? If I remove that one, are there any probs?
2. If `AgentVersion` is `null` or not getting any value or any strings other than numeric values I want to assign AgentVersion to value '0.0.0.0' otherwise i will
   display the numeric value which is coming. Is this code below sufficient here
   `string.IsNullOrEmpty(AgentVersion) ? "0.0.0.0" : AgentVersion;` If then where and how can I implement in 'Property'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You don't need to instantiate `m_version` as null in this context.  You usually only need to do this when declaring a local variable, to avoid the 'Use of unassigned local variable *[name]*' compile error. So `private string m_version;` will suffice.

2) For checking null and empty values, what you have with `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` is fine.  If you want to go check your property returns strings in the correct format, you can use `Regex.IsMatch()` to ensure the property only ever returns strings in version number-format.

```
[DefaultValue("0.0.0.0")]
public string AgentVersion
{
    get
    {
        return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(m_version ?? String.Empty, @"\A\d+[.]\d+[.]\d+[.]\d+\z") 
            ? m_version 
            : "0.0.0.0";
    }
}

private string m_version;
```

My regular expressions are a bit rusty, so someone can probably improve on what I have here, but it's the general gist of what you need.

Answer (score 2):

1. As the value of `m_version` is always assigned in the constructor you don't need setting it to `null`.
2. `get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_version) ? "0.0.0.0" : m_version; }`

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use Resharper, it will show you where you have redundant declarations. In this case it is redundant.
2. If `String.Empty` is a valid value you can implement it using

   `public string AgentVersion
   {
       get { return m_version ?? "0.0.0.0"; }
   }`

otherwise you are correct use `String.IsNullOrEmpty`

```
public string AgentVersion
{
    get { return String.IsNullOrEmpty(m_version) ? "0.0.0.0":m_version; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code.

```
public string AgentVersion 
 {
    get
    { 
        if(string.isNullOrEmpty(m_version))
        {
            string keySpoPath = SpoRegistry.SpoAgentRoot;
            RegistryKey regkey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keySpoPath);
            m_version = (string)regkey.GetValue(SpoRegistry.regValue_CurrentVersion);
        }
             m_version = string.isNullOrEmpty(m_version) ? m_version : "0.0.0.0";
                 return m_version;
        } 

}
string m_version;
```

Comment: two isNullOrEmpty checkings are there Is it required?

Comment: m_version = string.isNullOrEmpty(m_version) ? m_version : "0.0.0.0";
                 return m_version; should be changed to   m_version = string.isNullOrEmpty(m_version) ? "0.0.0.0": m_version ;
                 return m_version; rite??

Comment: basically in if block, if m_version is null, it gets the value from registry. It may happen that registry value is deleted or not exist so the second isNullOrEmpty statement checks if m_version is null or empty, it return "0.0.0.0".